# I pressed c in editing mode and can't get back

Tags: wireframe

[image]

can somebody help me? I'm on my Mac Book Pro (without Numpad - I KNOW) and I need a shortcut or something to untag the object. I can't press any other button and I don't know when I saved it the last time. Please help meeee.

Comment: press the **Esc** key

Answer (score 4):

the Esc key should get you out if it. You can also use your non-dominant click(left or right).

Comment: Brilliant! - ESC is usually my 'go to' to get out of sticky situations, but didn't think to try it when Blender locked up after pressing C (newb). Any idea why this happens? I'm using Blender 3.4 on Windows 11. Basically, I am trying to use 'C' to select an object with paintbrush cursor (as demonstrated in Blender tutorial), but it ain't working.